# Webpack resolve.modules does not work in vscode with typescript?

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, frontend

my simple webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

const developmentMode = 'development'
const configFactory = () => {
  let plugins = [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __DEV__: developmentMode,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/index.html'),
      inject: true,
    }),
  ]

  const config = {
    mode: developmentMode,
    entry: {
      app: path.resolve('./src/app/app.jsx'),
    },
    output: {
      filename: 'outputFileName',
      path: path.resolve('../dist'),
    },
    devtool: true,
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: require.resolve('ts-loader'),
            }
          ]

        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.jsx', '.js'],
      modules: [path.resolve('node_modules'), path.resolve('src/lib')],
    },
    plugins,
  };
  return config
}

module.exports = configFactory;
```

my tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "",
        "jsx": "react",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "dom",
            "scripthost",
            "dom.iterable"
        ],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "allowJs": false,
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        // "paths": {
        //   "*": ["lib/*"]
        // }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

i used resolve.modules in the webpack. The configuration in webpack is as follows:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.jsx', '.js'],
  modules: [path.resolve('node_modules'), path.resolve('src/lib')],
},
```

*src/lib/helios.ts* as follow:

```
export default function() {
  return 'helios-lib'
}
```

i use this lib/helios with other file as follow:

```
import helios from 'helios';
```

This is ok in runtime, but VSCODE prompts a **[ts] Cannot find module 'helios'. [2307]**.

The current solution is to configure paths in tsconfig, as follow:

```
"paths": {
  "*": ["lib/*"]
}
```

But doing this is a little tricks, which is not conducive to the later scalability.

Is there any good solution? please

- webpack version: 4.19.1
- webpack-cli version: 3.1.1
- typescript version: 2.9.x